# Swift, math functions and protocols

Tags: function, math, swift, protocols

I'm trying to create 2 protocols ArithmeticType and MathematicType that will be used in where clauses of generic operator functions

```
protocol ArithmeticType {
    func +(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    func -(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    func *(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    func /(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
}

extension Int : ArithmeticType {
}

extension Double : ArithmeticType {
}

extension Float : ArithmeticType {
}
```

ArithmeticType works as expected and either Int, Float and Double conform to it. However the following fails

```
import Darwin

protocol MathematicType {
    func sin(x: Self) -> Self
}

extension Double : MathematicType {
}

extension Float : MathematicType {
}
```

on console output of the playground I read:

```
Playground execution failed: <EXPR>:35:1: error: type 'Double' does not conform to protocol 'MathematicType'
extension Double : MathematicType {
^
<EXPR>:32:10: note: protocol requires function 'sin' with type 'Double -> Self'
    func sin(x: Self) -> Self
         ^
<EXPR>:39:1: error: type 'Float' does not conform to protocol 'MathematicType'
extension Float : MathematicType {
^
<EXPR>:32:10: note: protocol requires function 'sin' with type 'Float -> Self'
    func sin(x: Self) -> Self
         ^
```

I would like that math functions behave like the operators above. Is there any way?

== EDIT:

Now I realize that trying to simplify my question was a bad idea. the context is this class (vector of optional values)

```
class Vector<T> {

    var data=[T?]()

    init(fromArray: Array<T>) {
        for i in fromArray {
            data.append(i)
        }
    }

    init() {
    }

    init(count: Int){
        for i in 0..<count {
            data.append(nil)
        }
    }

    init(count: Int, repeatedValue: T) {
        for i in 0..<count {
            data.append(repeatedValue)
        }
    }

    func count() -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    func append(newElement: T?) {
        data.append(newElement)
    }

    subscript(index: Int) -> T? {
        let i = index>0 ? index % count() : -index % count()
        return data[i]
    }
}
```

outside of it I defined a generic function for the + operator

```
func +<T where T: ArithmeticType>(left: Vector<T>, right: Vector<T>) -> Vector<T> {
    let resultCount = max(left.count(),right.count())
    var result = Vector<T>()
    for i in 0..<resultCount {
        if left[i] != nil && right[i] != nil {
            result.append(left[i]!+right[i]!)
        }
        else {
            result.append(nil)
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

that works as expected, however when I tried to define a generic sin function as

```
func sin<T where T : FloatingPointType>(x: Vector<T>) -> Vector<T>{
    var result = Vector<T>()
    for i in 0..<x.count() {
        if let o = x[i] {
            result.append(sin(o))
        }
        else {
            result.append(nil)
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

I got "could not find an overload of sin that accepts the supplied arguments"

then my attempt with MathemticType trying to mimic what I already done for + operator

(ArithmeticType was inspired from IntegerAritmeticType source found by command clicking on import swift more than my knowledge of what I was doing)

== UPDATE

If I write a specialized function only for Double

```
func sin(x: Vector<Double>) -> Vector<Double>{
    var result = Vector<Double>()
    for i in 0..<x.count() {
        if let o = x[i] {
            result.append(Darwin.sin(o))
        }
        else {
            result.append(nil)
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

it works as expected.

So the question may become "How can I generalize this to either Double and Float" ?

Comment: I think if you want a type to conform to multiple protocols, you should do it like this: `extension Double : MathematicType, ArithmeticType {
}`

Comment: You're right, however I kept them apart to point out where my problem is

Comment: Your `func sin<T where T : FloatingPointType>` example looks good, except it can't call the standard library `sin` without checking and casting its argument -- see my answer and its new comments.

Comment: @rickster I don't see the point to check type inside the `func sin<T where T : FloatingPointType>` opposed to have a couple of specialized `func sin(x: Vector<Double>) -> Vector<Double>` and the same for Float. In both cases this is a **strong** limitation for generic programming. I wonder whether free functions were left out deliberately from generic programming or simply Apple didn't think they could be useful.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler error is because you declared `sin()` as a method of the `MathematicType` protocol, and then declared that `Double` implements `MathematicType`, but didn't actually write the `sin()` method.

```
extension Double {
    func sin(x: Double) -> Double {
        return Darwin.sin(x)
    }
}
```

I don't think that's what you want, though, is it? You want to be able to write this:

```
let myAngle = 3.14159
let sineValue = myAngle.sin()
```

If that's the case, your protocol and extension would need to look like this:

```
protocol MathematicType {
    func sin() -> Self
}

extension Double : MathematicType {
    func sin() -> Double {
        return Darwin.sin(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I definitely don't want a method, rather I need to use the sin function with a generic type T that can be Float or Double, see my edits in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Your `MathematicType` protocol, and your declarations of conformance to it in `Float` and `Double` extensions, say that `Float` and `Double` should provide `sin` as an instance method. That is, you're saying one should be able to write code like:

```
let zero = 0.0    // inferred type Double
zero.sin(1.5707963268) // returns about 1.0
```

Notice that invocation of `sin` isn't actually related to the value of `zero`, so this probably isn't the behavior you want.

You're probably looking to have `sin` be a free function, so you can just write:

```
sin(1.5707963268)
```

Right?

In that case, your work is already done... the standard library defines both:

```
func sin(x: Double) -> Double
func sin(x: Float) -> Float
```

If what you actually want is for your `MathematicType` to be usable as a generic parameter, meaning "a type you can take the sine of", you'll need a generic `sin` function. Something like this (quick kludgy solution, there's probably better):

```
func sine<T: FloatingPointType>(x: T) -> T {
    if let v = x as? Double {
        return sin(v) as T
    }
    if let v = x as? Float {
        return sin(v) as T
    }
    fatalError("unknown FloatingPointType")
}
```

(Notice also that there's already a protocol that both `Float` and `Double` conform to, so I've used that in the example.)

Comment: From your answer I understand that inside protocol braces I declare "methods" so, what I still don't understand is: 1) are the operators in ArithmeticType methods? I believed they were free functions. 2) why arithmetic operators and the sin function are different?

Comment: 1. Operators are the exception to the usual rules for protocol declarations. You define operators as free functions (i.e. at global scope), but you make them requirements of a protocol by listing them within the `protocol`.

Comment: 2. `sin` is not an operator, and operators are the only free functions that can be listed as requirements of a protocol. If you want a function that operates on multiple types, write a generic function. If you want your generic function to pass its generic parameter to a standard library function that takes a specific type, you'll have to check and cast the type... like in the generic `sine` function in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that operator requirements and instance method requirements are different, even though they syntactically look similar. Operators are always defined at the global level, so an operator requirement is a requirement on an operator at the global level. On the other hand, instance method requirements are requirements on instance methods. There is no way to specify a global function requirement.